# Выпадающее меню сss

Tags: html, css

Необходимо сделать чтобы был изображен круг, при наведении на который открывалось выпадающее меню с текстом. Буду рад любой подсказке.

```css
.maindiv{
  background-color: #78a2b7;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 40px 10px 40px 40px;
}
#maindiv_1{
  width: 25%; 
  float:left; 
}
#ul_1{
  background-color: #0000FF;
  width: 6%;
  height: 3%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  transition: 5s; 
}
#ul_1:hover{
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
  display: list-item;
  transition: 5s;
  border-radius: 40px 10px 40px 40px;
  border-bottom-width: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id='maindiv_1' class='maindiv'>
  <div id='ul_1'>
    <ul>
      <li>Номер один</li>
      <li>Номер два</li>
      <li>Номер три</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а что не работает? кроме того что это не круг

Comment: всё работает, нужен только круг)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  width: 4.5em;
  height: 4.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 2.25em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: transparent;
  transition: 3s;
}

ul:hover {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2.25em 10px 2.25em 2.25em;
  color: white;
}

li {
  padding-left: 2.25em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Номер один</li>
  <li>Номер два</li>
  <li>Номер три</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: всё правильно, только при наведении менюшка должна выпадать вправо и вниз

Answer (score 0):

Это похоже на круг

```css
.maindiv{
  background-color: #78a2b7;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px; 
  float:left;
}
#ul_1{
  background-color: #0000FF;
  width: 6%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 5s; 
}
#ul_1:hover{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: list-item;
  transition: 5s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-width: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id='maindiv_1' class='maindiv'>
  <div id='ul_1'>
    <ul>
      <li>Номер один</li>
      <li>Номер два</li>
      <li>Номер три</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь, в итоге получилось следующее...

HTML

```
<ul> 
<li id='li_1'>Произвольный текст 1</li> 
<li id='li_2'>Произвольный текст 2</li> 
<li id='li_3'>Произвольный текст 3</li> 
</ul>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-color: #e6e6fa;
}
@keyframes traffic{
 100%{color: white;}
}
#div_1{
    width: 3%;
    height: 3%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition-property: width, height;
    transition-delay: 0s, 2s;
    transition-duration: 2s, 3s;    
}
#div_1:hover{
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: list-item;
    transition-property: width, height;
    transition-delay: 0s, 2s;
    transition-duration: 2s, 3s;
}
#div_1:hover #li_1{
    animation: traffic 5s 5s forwards;
}
#div_1:hover #li_2{
    animation: traffic 5s 7s forwards;
}
#div_1:hover #li_3{
    animation: traffic 5s 9s forwards;
}
```